# Custom PFQeryTableView

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and I'd like to make a PFQueryTableViewController display sort of a calendar. It roughly looks like [this](http://cloud.b%C3%BCckst%C3%BCcke.com/image/2d180r0x1x1q).

Something that I totally don't understand is how am I able to write my own PFTableViewCell? Or do I even have to use it or whatever. I just want the label to display the text I entered on Parse.com.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just override [cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3aobject%3a) to return a cell of your custom class.